# Explanation of confidence interval in example in Gelman and Hill

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation

Gelman and Hill have an example in their text where they analyze [this birth related dataset](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/examples/girls/births.txt).  I understand the idea behind the analysis, but I can't verify the actual confidence interval  that they get:

```
Total proportion girls:                                              .4857
Observed standard deviation of proportion girls:                     .0064
Expected s.d. of proportion girls:  sqrt((.486)(1-.486)/3903) =      .0080
95% conf. interval for observed s.d. (based on chi^2 with 23 d.f.): (.006, .010)
```

I'm familiar with the approach to generate the confidence interval outlined [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section2/prc231.htm) , but they seem to be using a different method.  Can anyone point me to the technique they use?

Comment: With 3903 girls the estimate of the binomial proportion is approximately normal.  Then its estimate of variance should be proportional to a chi-square.  But the degrees of freedom should be close to the sample size if 3903 (I would think) in which case a normal approximation to the chi square should be warranted (note the estimate is close to 0.5 so these normal approximations should be very accurate.  A confidence interval centered at (0.008)$^2$ using + or - 1.96 time the standard deviation from the normal approximation would give the 95% confidence interval for the variance.

Comment: The corresponding CI for the standard deviation would be obtained by taking the square root of the lower and upper endpoints for its lower and upper endpoints.  The interval for the variance would be symmetric around the estimate.  The interval for the standard deviation would not.  But it could be nearly symmetric since the estimates are so small. This may be how to get their estimate but the use of chi-square 23 df is a mystery.

Comment: I agree that the estimate of variance for the total population is what you said.  But we're trying to estimate variance for the 24 samples.

Comment: I am confused as to why the analysis of the 24 separate months is better than analysis of the 3903 points that are pretty much independent. I know that the gender of an alligator is determined by the temperature at hatching (http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v296/n5860/abs/296850a0.html), so fluctuations of the environment have a legitimate effect on gender. However, I am failing to see why the standard deviation has to come from 24 observations rather than 3903 observations and the binomial model. (TBC)

Comment: In many other situations, I would object to an indiscriminate application of models that may give poor approximation to reality, and would be especially suspicious to the CIs based on the standard errors that assume independence when in fact the data come in chunks. If we were talking about precipitation, say, then of course I would yell out loud that we should treat these observations as clustered in months or seasons, at least. But the gender of a newborn?... I am lost.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I looked at the observed birth data, I see that there are 24 months of data.  For each month you have a sample proportion of girl births.  If we assume that births are independent of month then each estimate is approximately normal with mean the true p and variance p(1-p)/n$_i$ where n$_i$ is the actual number of girl births in month i.  So you have 24 independent estimates of  p.  Each one normally distributed.  The variances differ slightly becuase of the differences in the n$_i$s.  But since the ns are all close to 3900 we can ignore that difference.

Now 0.4857 is the overall average of these 24 estimates.  Take the sample variance of these 24 estimates.  If each estimate were exactly normal and independent the variance would be proportional to a chi square random variable with 23 degrees of freedom (1 less than the number of months).  Since the normal approximations are all very good that chi square distribution can be used to get a confidence interval for the variance and then the square root of the end points can be used for the approximate 95% confidence interval for the standard deviation.

I think that what is very interesting about this is the upper endpoint of 0.010.  We see that if we add 0.01 to the estimate of 0.4857 for girls we still get 0.4957 <0.5.  This indicates that we would reject the null hypothesis that p=0.5.  So we have evidence that slightly more girls are born than boys.  The actual hypothesis test though would be gotten by inverting say the 95% confidence interval for p which is [0.4742, 0.4972] (barely excluding 0.5).  I got the CI by subtracting 1.96 (0.0064) from 0.4857 for the lower endpoint and adding that quantity to 0.4857 for the upper endpoint.

Comment: Hi Michael,  Your method of bounding the CI for the variance does not give the numbers in the example as near as I can tell.  Did you compute this?

Comment: Also, if our estimate is for standard deviation is .01, then we would not reject the null hypothesis at the 95% level because we would have to add two (1.96) standard deviations, right?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can talk about $\chi^2$ only if the underlying normal variables have identically the same variance. In this example, they have different sample sizes $n_i$, and hence different variances. The overall mean (proportion) would be normal, but its variance will be complicated, and the Satterthwaite approximation to the degrees of freedom would give something a bit smaller than 23 d.f.s.

Answer (score 0):

10 years late...

However, to calculate the 95% confidence interval, the following R code is what you need:

```
expected_std = 0.0080
df = 24 - 1

q95 = sqrt(
  (df*expected_std^2) / qchisq(c(0.025, 0.975), df, lower.tail = FALSE))
```

Essentially, one scales the expected variance (expected_std^2) by $\frac{df}{\chi^2}$ where $\chi^2$ are the values given by the $\chi^2$ distribution at the quantiles of interest: (0.025, 0.975). We then take the square root to convert from variance to standard deviation.

A useful [resource](http://ianmadd.github.io/pages/Confidence_Intervals_Part4.html).